# Why Safari doesn't open Google search results in the new tab?

Tags: safari

In the Safari browser, Google website, search results used to open in a new tab, but at some point they started opening in the same tab and that's very inconvenient for me.

I have not found a solution to this myself. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not a setting of safari, but google itself. click on link bellow:

https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en

and navigate to:

> Where results open
>
> Open each selected result in a new browser window

and check that checkbox and save your settings

Comment: A new window is not the same as a new tab.